# Please help me to run my first android app

Tags: android, emulation

From last 2 days I have tried everything uninstalled and installed eclipse, sdk and adt plugin several times, tried everything on every single post on stackoverflow and other forums but nothing is working for me. I am trying to run MyfirstApp hello world program on emulator but emulator always hangs on -

Starting activity com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity on device emulator-5554

and never displays anything on the emulator screen. I waited hours to see if something happen, log cat show some processing though all the time. I have also seen something like -Can not find class java.lang.utilities etc in the logcat.

my computer configuration is as follow -

1.3 GHz Intel atom processor 
1 GB Ram 
160 GB hard disk

I was so motivated at start but this thing has frustrated me, any suggestion and help will be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK found solution to my problem. Hopefully it helps you as well.  My app was running in the background.  I unlocked the phone and my app was there the whole time.

http://androidforums.com/application-development/118051-hello-android-stops-running-eclipse-can-not-display-app-emulator.html